# How to write complex constraints in Python Pulp

Tags: python, optimization, model, constraints, pulp

I need to write some complex constraints by using python pulp.  Here is an example,

Assume I have three sets `A=[1,2,3,4], B=[A1,A2,A3,A4], and C=[C1,C2,C3]`

and three parameters `weight[a, b], amount[a, b, c], flag[a, b, c]`, where `flag[a, b, c] = 1` only for a few scenarios of indices, say only `flag["1", "A1", "C1"] = 1` and `flag["2", "A2", "C3"] = 1`.

Then, I need to define a constraint with a summation of amount[a, b, c] over c only when flag[(a, b, c)] == 1, a constraint like the following one.  I am struggling to find a correct way to handle this logic as I often see an error noting some combinations of (a, b, c) are not available for flag[(a, b, c)] after I define a set of index c by indices a and b.

```py
for a in A.index: 
    for b in B.index: 
        model += weight[a, b] <= pulp.lpSum([amount[a, b, c] for c in C.index if flag[(a, b, c)] == 1]);
```

Do you know how to write such a constraint?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You're missing crucial data from your description: which are variables and which are constants? And what happens about the `(a, b, c)` you don't care about because `flag[a, b, c] == 0`? Do they not contribute to `weight[a, b]` or should their `amount[a, b, c]` be 0?